# Filter/parse/modify emails and hrefs from html content in PHP4

Tags: html, regex, email, parsing, php4

I'm not validating emails. What I want to do is find (and then change) 3 separate types of "email" content in a (html) string:

1. a plain email: eg user@test.com
2. a mailto href: eg `<a href="mailto:user@test.com">user@test.com</a>`
3. an aliased href: eg `<a href="mailto:user@test.com">user's email</a>`

I'm then going to transform each example into a custom html string that will then be modified by JS (anti-spam harvesting via Spamspan):

```
<span class="spamspan">
<span class="u">user</span>
@
<span class="d">example.com</span>
(<span class="t">Spam Hater</span>)
</span>
```

So you can see I also have to find these types of input, parse the email into user, domain and (optionally) a display value. I'm struggling at the moment with regexes to find these emails... parsing them should be straightfoward in PHP.

Edit: At the moment, I'm locked into PHP4. Will take a look at http://php-html.sourceforge.net/ for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and an [email regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: I had to use http://php-html.sourceforge.net/ (which is what simplehtmldom is based off) due to the server running PHP4 (alas!). 

Key points: preg_match_all(), substr_replace() and some regexes.

Comment: Just ran into a bug - my regex for "plain" emails means that emails inside form fields are converted... I'll need to skip these :)

Comment: My solution was to use a regex to pull input fields out of the string and replace them with a string "token" (which is left alone by email regexes), then re-sub the original content back in after my email processing is completed.

I really need to upgrade the server to PHP5! :)